# What CSS attributes can be used to control the pager?

Tags: html, css, xpages

I have a repeat custom control with a pager. In the designer the text ("previous 1|2|3|4|5 Next") is aligned on right; unfortunately when displayed on server this text is left aligned. I've tried to add the `text-align: right` to the font parameter of the style, without any success. The server is also unable to extend a `xp:div` to the CSS specified size (width: 800px).

I'm in 8.5.3 release. Does anyone had this kind of problem?

Comment: Server do never act on CSS. Browsers do. When you inspect the HTML send to the browser you can see where your CSS goes - and why it doesn't have the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

Will you please clarify the question. And paste the pager source then will have better idea.
If you have selected the pager control and given the alignment property as Right, then you source should show as follows.

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1" panelPosition="right"></xp:pager>
```

Comment: Here is the control : "<xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialRefresh="true" for="repeatQuestions" id="pagerQuestion" disableTheme="true" outerStyleClass="repeatEntete"    style="font-family:Arial;text-align:right" panelPosition="right">
  </xp:pager>" -- As I've told the texte appears right aligned in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style="float:right"` in pager control although it is not best practice to add CSS styles to XPages or Custom Controls.

Find out which CSS class the pager element is associated with (with developer tools in browser). It should be class `xspPagerRight`. Look also for the source where `float: right` is overwritten with `left`. If you can't change it there then you have to "overwrite" it. Create a Style Sheets file under Resources and put in

```
.xspPagerRight {
    float: right;
}
```

Then add it as a resource to your XPages or theme.

Comment: Ok it works (I suppose I'll never know why !); thank you very much. Have you any idea about the xp:div which stays at 500px width when It has a 800px style ?

Comment: I am glad it works. Please research about the CSS setting for this div in rendered page in browser. There you see where ii is set to 500px and can change it there.

Comment: here is a link with the description how to "research" on a rendered page: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ If you don't use chrome look here: http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools

Answer (score 0):

Note about the question : why the title is different of what it was when I created it ?